# Labeling of binary image

Tags: image, matlab

How can i label connected components  in a image like one components as 1,other as 2 and so  on .Can you write an example code of it using MATLAB.Explain the other technique if it is not possible in binary image.I want to label it using 4 neighbour connected component algorithm.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

See [bwlabel](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html) which seems to be exactly what you want. It's very self-explanatory.

Comment: My requirement is not to use any built-in function of Matlab.